# No clear way to alert sender applications of new media fetched by the receiver application

Tags: google-cast

I am attempting to implement support for an application that serves playlists of music content over chrome cast. In the current implementation the sender application sends each individual track, one at a time, to the receiver, which then plays the track and reports back status. This model does not work terribly well on iOS devices and so I would like to flip the model and make the receiver responsible for fetching new tracks and notifying the client when there is a new track so that they can update their UI.

Currently I have set up the receiver to call MediaManager.setMediaInformation when the new track is loaded and set the broadcast parameter to true. On Android I am using the following code to listen for new media and for updates on the status of existing media:

```
RemoteMediaPlayer remoteMediaPlayer = getRemoteMediaPlayer();

remoteMediaPlayer.setOnMetadataUpdatedListener(
    new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnMetadataUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMetadataUpdated() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Metadata updated");
        }
    }
});

remoteMediaPlayer.setOnStatusUpdatedListener(
    new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnStatusUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusUpdated() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Status update");
        }
     }
});
```

The OnMetadataUpdatedListener is called when the receiver loads its first track, but each additional track that is loaded only causes the OnStatusUpdatedListener to be called. I can certainly see the new metadata for the track in the OnStatusUpdatedListener once the track has started playing, but from the API documentation it sounds like OnMetadataUpdatedListener should be called when the metadata (and the track) has been updated.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong here or further steps to debug the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: HI. Did you ever solve this problem? It seems we are running into the same issue. thanks

Comment: Same here.....any developments with this?